# Queryable Attribute allow to get some properties not all of them

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

I have a web api 2 application, and in my controller , I have this code :

```
    [Queryable]
    public IQueryable<Title> GetTitles()
    {
        return db.Titles;
    }
```

and here is the Title entity :

```
public partial class Title
{
    public Title()
    {
        this.People = new HashSet<Person>();
    }

    public short Id { get; set; }
    public string NameT { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Person> People { get; set; }
}
```

When people query the Titles, they must get only "NameT" property. but now they get all of the properties. and yes, I know about $select, but I want another way. means even they use $select, they should not able to get "Id" property for example. if I have to bring more information, please tell me. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to solve your problem when you use ODataController. However, they won't affect ApiController non-query part.

In that condition, you can try what Zoe suggested.

1.Ignore those properties while building your model with model builder.

`builder.EntityType<Title>().Ignore(title => title.Id);`

2.Add ignore member attributes on those properties.

`[IgnoreDataMember]
public short Id { get; set; }`

More than these, we provide support for limiting the set of allowed queries in Web API 2.2 for OData v4.0.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/03/13/getting-started-with-asp-net-web-api-2-2-for-odata-v4-0.aspx

We can use attributes like Unsortable, NonFilterable, NotExpandable or NotNavigable on the properties of the types in our model, or we can configure this explicitly in the model builder.

Comment: I'm using ODataConventionModelBuilder , I can't get Ignore method!! what's wrong with it?! And do you know when the stable version will be released? Thanks.

Comment: I could use another class, bind Title to it, and use that class for operation. this odata just work with properties that I want to.

Comment: I don't know the exact date for webapi 2.2 rtm release. But I think the Ignore method is already in Web Api 2.1, you can create a web application with Web Api in Visual Studio and try it out. What about "builder.Entity<Title>().Ignore(title => title.Id)"? Does the IgnoreDataMember attribute work?

Comment: You can update your webapi.odata reference to latest or preview version.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can have filter in your action `GetTitles()`, like:

```
[Queryable]
public IQueryable<Title> GetTitles()
{
    return db.Titles.Select(t=>t.Name);
}
```

Comment: ofcourse it won't work because it's not IQueryable<Title> return type. but I can use it another way,however. I have another question, how to select multiple properties with Select method, not just one, for exmaple "Name" and "Rate"? Thanks.

Comment: Can you try `return db.Titles.Select(t=>new Title{Name=t.Name, Rate=t.Rate})`;

Answer (score 0):

Use the ODataModelBuilder class as opposed to the ODataConventionModelBuilder class.

```
var modelBuilder = new ODataModelBuilder();

var titles = modelBuilder.EntitySet<Title>("titles");

var title = titles.EntityType;

title.HasKey(x => x.Id);
title.Ignore(x => x.Id);
title.Property(x => x.TName);

titles.HasIdLink(x => { return x.GenerateSelfLink(true); }, true);
config.Routes.MapODataRoute("odata", "odata", modelBuilder.GetEdmModel());
```